# Autoreload jqgrid and stop when editing

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to implement autorefresh grid, and stop when user edit/add/search, so I use clearInterval in ondblClickRow event (since I use inline edit).

So, my problem is when and where to restart de autoreload. I try in the loadComplete event, which seems to be the beter place, BUT everytime loadComplete fires setInterval() to reloadGrid, it "multiplies" the reloadGrid call!
In other words, first time (after 8 seconds) it reloads ok. Second time it call 2 reloads. Third time it call 4 reloads. Fourth time it calls 8 reloads, and so on... which means many ajax requests each time!

What is incorrect? I would appreciate some help, thanks!

Here is my code:

```
var mySeconds = 10 * 1000; //seconds *1000
var myTimer;

function autoReloadGrid($grid) {
    $grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]);
};

var $myGrid = $("#myGrid");

$myGrid.jqGrid({ 
    //grid options here...

    ondblClickRow: function(rowId) {
        clearInterval(myTimer);     
        //editRow here...
    },

    loadComplete: function() {
        console.log('myTimer = ' + myTimer);
        myTimer = setInterval( function() { autoReloadGrid($myGrid) }, mySeconds);
    }
 })
```

Note: I test the myTimer value using console.log and it shows a different ID every time it fires.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your code is the following: you can create **multiple** timers which execute `autoReloadGrid`. You cancel only **the last** created timer inside of `ondblClickRow`.

It's important to understand that `loadComplete` can be executed multiple times: on paging, sorting and so on. So I recommend you to include call of `clearInterval` before `setInterval`.

Comment: Thank you!
So as you said, is this correct?

    loadComplete: function() {
          clearInterval(myTimer); 
          myTimer = setInterval( function() { autoReloadGrid($myGrid) }, mySeconds);

    }

Comment: @Aberel: Yes, it should work. You can replace `clearInterval(myTimer);` to `if (myTimer !== undefined) { clearInterval(myTimer); }`, but it's not really required.